# Is it possible to achieve an automatic restart cron job by using Node.js PM2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I’ve been facing a problem where one of the Cron jobs processes was suddenly killed or crashed. I’m using PHP MVC on Cloudways as my server. Previously I used node.js pm2 to restarted the cron job manually on cloudways terminal.

I would like to ask that is it possible to achieve restart cron job process automatically by using Node.js PM2?